# Automatically move this discussion to chat: Reputation, not yet enough

Tags: feature-request, reputation, chat

While commenting I found that a link comes and says **Automatically move to this discussion to Chat**. But when I clicked on link for chat it shows **Reyaz has only 13 reputation, not yet enough to chat**.

It is shown in the picture below:

> [image]

I am asking for a feature where it should check first that does OP has enough rep to chat or not hen only link saying Continue in Chat....

Comment: Sorry for confusing pic, even I got confused after page Load. :)